# Getting Phone number from Contacts of contact with multiple phones

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to get a contact that have more than one phone number listed.
I've started an activity and got to pick a contact, but now i want to present to the user to pick the phone of the specific contact that has more the one phone listed.
I've managed to pick from the list of phones of all contacts, but i want to first pick a contact and then pick the phone number.

How to i achieve this? Should I start a new activity for this?

Thank you.

Comment: When I made a contact picker (old and probably un-supported code now), I had a list of names and when a user selected one, a custom `AlertDialog` would show all of the numbers available for the user to select. I would start there. A brand new activity for something like that seems like overkill to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [android_contact_picker](https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker)

#### Example usage:

If you just want to open a contacts picker from within your app and then get a number, do this:

```
private static final int GET_PHONE_NUMBER = 3007;

public void getContact() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ContactsPickerActivity.class), GET_PHONE_NUMBER);
}

// Listen for results.
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // See which child activity is calling us back.
    switch (requestCode) {
        case GET_PHONE_NUMBER:
            // This is the standard resultCode that is sent back if the
            // activity crashed or didn't doesn't supply an explicit result.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else {
                String phoneNumber = (String) data.getExtras().get(ContactsPickerActivity.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER);  
                //Do what you wish to do with phoneNumber e.g.
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Phone number found: " + phoneNumber , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```